# Regex to identify roman numerals followed by " - " at the start of a line

Tags: python, regex, roman-numerals

I am trying to create a regex expression that matches roman numerals (from 1 to 99) followed by " - " or by " – ". It should only match if the roman numeral is at the start of a line. I want to add a newline before each match. The example string is:

```
VI - lealdade e ética;  
VII - busca da verdade real;  
VIII - livre convencimento técnico-jurídico do delegado de polícia;  
IX - controle de legalidade dos atos policiais civis;  
X - uso diferenciado da força para preservação da vida, redução do sofrimento e o inciso  
II redução de danos;  
XI – continuidade investigativa  
criminal;  
XII – atuação imparcial na condução da atividade  
investigativa e de polícia judiciária;  
XIII – política de gestão direcionada à proteção e  
à valorização dos seus  
integrantes;  
XIV – unidade de doutrina e uniformidade de  
procedimento;  
XV – autonomia, imparcialidade, tecnicidade e cientificidade investigativa, indiciatória, inquisitória, notarial e pericial; "
```

Using the pattern `r'^(I{1,3}|IV|V|VI{1,3}|IX|X{1,3}|XL|L -|– )'`, I can insert a newline before each roman numerals followed by " - " or " – ".
The problem is that it is also inserting a newline before "II redução de danos;". How can I correct this behaviour?

Using the pattern `r'^(I{1,3}|IV|V|VI{1,3}|IX|X{1,3}|XL|L) (?:-|–) '`, I can insert a newline only before roman numerals followed by " - ". Why?

Comment: The hyphen is a red herring. The regex doesn't cover XI, among others.

Comment: I think trying to match only valid roman numerals may be overkill. Just match `[IVXL]+` to match the digits in any sequence. False positives are unlikely, since there are no common words consisting only of these letters (in English, not sure about Portugese).

Comment: Try: `^[IVXL]+(?=\s*\-)` with a positive lookahead.

Comment: @Corralien: why do you put the roman numerals outside of the lookahead?

Comment: @Corralien: I was thinking about: `^(?=[IVXLCM]+ [-\u2010-\u2015] )` to avoid a reference in the replacement string.

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/oNI3Lu/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Your expression matches the start of the line: match '^' only if it followed by a roman numeral. https://regex101.com/r/pZ37b1/2

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. The problem is not how to match the roman numerals but how to match real cases (start of line, ..., followed by a dash, etc).

Answer (score 0):

With 99 values, there's both a great many and complex combinations for a regex, while not so many a simple list isn't easy to create and manage - consider either just testing if the line `.startswith(tuple_of_values)` the values or building your regex programmatically from it

```py
mapping = {
    "I": 1,
    "II": 2,
    ...
    "XCIX": 100,
}

numerals_regex = re.compile("^(" + str("|".join(mapping.keys())) + ") (-|–) (.*)$")

for line in lines:
    match = numerals_regex.match(line.rstrip())
    if match is None:
        # opportunity to deal with line in some other way
        continue
    # line matched!
```